# Unable to use both Swift and Obj-C libs with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, realm

I have just started a new Swift project and I would like to use different libraries. In particular, I would like to use Realm.io, an Obj-C library. But, I would also like to use pure Swift libraries such as Alamofire or Dollar.

I use Cocoapods for managing my dependencies. I use the latest version (0.37.0) and the new `use_frameworks!` flag. `pod install` is successful anytime.

Unfortunately, when I try to build my project I get two errors (for my main target):

- `Umbrella header Realm.h not found` from `module.modulemap`
- `Could not build Objective-C module Realm` from any file using `import Realm`

Other imports work fine.

I have noticed the following: if I remove pure Swift libs and `use_frameworks`, everything works fine. I am aware about [this current issue from Cocoapods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/guides.cocoapods.org/issues/53). However, it should not be a problem for Realm asks developers to use that flag.

Here is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'rothrock' do
  pod 'Realm'
  pod 'Cent'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'Alamofire'
end

target 'rothrockTests', :exclusive => true do
end
```

I use no bridging header. Should I?

Any idea or workaround?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you're seeing. Would it be possible for you to share an example project that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Hey Sam, see my latest comment (Stefan's answer) below. It works using a bridging header.
It's maybe due to the different Cocoapods version I am using.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Alright, here is the full walkthrough:

1. Install dependencies using Cocoapods and the `use_frameworks!` flag.
2. As you need to use a Objective-C dependency, create a Bridging header. You can create one easily by importing an Objective-C class to your Swift project, than remove it (the wizard should ask you if need a bridging header). Otherwise, create a new header file. Then, navigate to your target configuration and enter the name of your file in `Swift Compiler - Code Generation` > `Objective-C Bridging header`.
3. Still in your target configuration, add a new entry in `Search Paths` > `User Header Search Paths`: `Pods` as value and flag it as recursive.
4. Remove any `import` instruction from your code, relative to your Objective-C library.
5. Build your project. You should have a success.

Comment: Thank you so much. You save my life !!

Answer (score 2):

You need a bridging header and import your Objective-C library headers there.

If you are using only Realm you can check out this documentation for Swift http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/ (go to CocoaPods down in the tabs)

**Swift**

1. Install CocoaPods 0.36.0 or later (`[sudo] gem install cocoapods`).
2. In your Podfile, add `use_frameworks!` and `pod 'Realm'` to your app target.
3. From the command line, run pod install.
4. Use the .xcworkspace file generated by CocoaPods to work on your project!
5. Download the latest release of Realm and extract the zip.
6. Drag the file at Swift/RLMSupport.swift into the File Navigator of your Xcode project, checking the Copy items if needed checkbox.

Comment: Using `#import "Realm/Realm.h"` in my header, I now get this error: `Realm/Realm.h not found`

Comment: This syntax is `#import <Realm/Realm.h>`, but if that doesn't work you might as well use their suggested method.

Comment: I followed their method and it did not work. I had the error I described previously in my question (umbrella header missing).

Comment: Have you tried with `#import <Realm/Realm.h>` in Bridging header?

Comment: Ok it works if I use a bridging header, remove all `import Realm` from my code and set `User Header Search Paths` to `Pods/**`` in my target config.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed the **Realm** library in a project I have with some of the libraries you mention above like **Alamofire** and **SwiftyJSON** and others and it works fine when you build the project and even put the `import Realm`, no compilation errors at all.

I'm using Cocoapods 0.36.0, the stable version and this is my PodFile :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks! 

platform :ios, '8.0'

link_with 'ApiWorkflow', 'ApiWorkflowTests'

pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
pod 'Typhoon', '~> 3.0'
pod 'SwiftCSV', '~> 0.1'
pod 'Realm'
```

I hope this help you